# open() fails on some files with sudo permission

Tags: mac, darwin

Running on Darwin Kernel Version 22.1.0.
I have a program which goes through the devices in `/dev/` directory to send an nvme command to them to get their ID information. On Linux the files I look for are of `/dev/nvmeX` variant, but on macOS the nvme devices look to be mapped to `/dev/diskX` or `rdiskX`.
I am using

```
//p_dev =/dev/rdisk0;1,2,3...
int fd = open(p_dev, O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
if (fd < 0)
{
    printf("ERROR: %d %s open() failed on %s\n", errno, strerror(errno), p_dev);
}
```

for `rdisk0..3` this returns,

```
ERROR: 1 Operation not permitted open() failed on /dev/rdisk0
ERROR: 16 Resource busy open() failed on /dev/rdisk1
ERROR: 1 Operation not permitted open() failed on /dev/rdisk2
ERROR: 1 Operation not permitted open() failed on /dev/rdisk3
```

Next, `rdisk4` is the device I am looking for and it opens without any issue. I am running my program with `sudo` so not permitted doesn't make sense.

I checked using `diskutil` and 0..3 are Apple's SSDs and its partitions. Are they somehow special? As far as I can tell from smartctl they are all NVMe devices.

I am not familiar with Apple's implementation and proper use so hopefully someone might know what I might be missing?

For now I worked around this by using:

```
popen("diskutil info %s | grep 'Media Name'", "r")
```

and looking for the relevant information.

From command line using `system_profiler SPNVMeDataType` shows the device Apple SSD and the `rdisk4` device but it doesn't show which device one or the other is in /dev/, neither is PCI vendor ID in the output.

```
system_profiler SPNVMeDataType
NVMExpress:
Apple SSD Controller:

    APPLE SSD AP0512Q:

      Capacity: 500.28 GB (500,277,792,768 bytes)
      TRIM Support: Yes
      Model: APPLE SSD AP0512Q
      Revision: 873.40.4
      Serial Number: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      Detachable Drive: No
      BSD Name: disk0
      Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
      Removable Media: No
      S.M.A.R.T. status: Verified
      Volumes:
        iSCPreboot:
          Capacity: 524.3 MB (524,288,000 bytes)
          BSD Name: disk0s1
          Content: Apple_APFS_ISC
        Macintosh HD:
          Capacity: 494.38 GB (494,384,795,648 bytes)
          BSD Name: disk0s2
          Content: Apple_APFS
        Recovery:
          Capacity: 5.37 GB (5,368,664,064 bytes)
          BSD Name: disk0s3
          Content: Apple_APFS_Recovery

Generic SSD Controller:

    xyz:

      Capacity: 123
      TRIM Support: No
      Model: xyz
      Revision: ---zzz
      Serial Number: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      Link Width: x4
      Link Speed: 8.0 GT/s
      Detachable Drive: No
      BSD Name: disk4
      Partition Map Type: Unknown
      Removable Media: No
      S.M.A.R.T. status: Verified
```

Using `system_profiler SPSerialATADataType` doesn't produce any output.

Comment: It’s important to note that Darwin/macOS ≠ Linux.  macOS typically limits the SATA/NVME commands you can send to drives.  Also, permission issues are likely due to [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).  What info are you looking to obtain?  Maybe there’s another method.

Comment: Can't seem to open the link. 
I am looking ideally for PCI Vendor ID or product name. smartctl provides PCI vendor ID but it isn't preinstalled.

Comment: The link should work.  If not, just search for “system integrity protection.”  For NVME info try `system…profiler SPNVMeDataType`. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, link finally opened.

Yes systemprofiler works but it doesn't provide where the device is mapped to in /dev/ or PCI vendor ID

Comment: See f what you’re looking for in `system_profiler SPSerialATADataType`

Comment: That doesn't output anything :/

Comment: Try `system_profiler SPPCIDataType` for PCI info and `mount` to see where the moint points map to

Comment: Thanks for the info, ```system_profiler SPPCIDataType``` does show the vendor ID but ```mount``` doesn't list that device.

I was hoping to understand a bit more on why ```open()``` failed for the Apple's rdisk. Since they are using NVMe protocol I was expecting that I can send an identify command through pread to check what kind of device it is. . I guess they fall under Apple's SIP so might need to modify the ```open``` some other way

Comment: If you're looking for the `/dev/****`, it will be the BSD name.  Just prepend `/dev/` to whatever the name is.

Comment: ```system_profiler SPPCIDataType``` doesn't show BSD. ```SPNVMeDataType``` does but no vendor ID.

Comment: Use those together to get the data you're looking for.  Fortunately and unfortunately, macOS locks things down tight for security - that's the good news.  The bad news is that they lock things down tight for security that common tools like the one you're trying to use don't work.

Comment: Got it thanks for the info. Will make use of those then.